# keeping python requests.session alive

Tags: python, nginx, python-requests

I'm using python's requests library to make requests to a far away server (rtt is around 300ms) running nginx with SSL termination.
this is my code:

```
s = request.Session()
s.get('https://example.com')  # runs in 1000 milliseconds
time.sleep(XXX)
s.get('https://example.com')  # runs in YYY milliseconds
```

When XXX's value is relatively small, less than 60 seconds, the second call runs in about 300ms (`YYY=300`) - skipping SSL handshake.

But when XXX's value is larger, at around 2 minutes or above, the call takes 1000 again as it has to redo the SSL handshake.

I'd like to have consequtive calls to my remote server run faster and skip SSL handshake after the first negotiation.

My remote server is running nginx, and I have tried to set `keepalive_timeout` to 10 minutes, but that didn't help caching the SSL credentials.

I tried to look for a way to control request.Session's timeout on connections, but couldn't see a way to control it (you can either set keepalive header on the HTTP or not).

Does anyone know how can I increase the amount of time till the Session object has to refresh the SSL connection?

Comment: Have you tried SSL session cache? http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_session_cache

Comment: Thanks @FaisalMemon, I have ssl_session_cache enabled.  The thing is that ssl caching/ connection reuse works as long as the successive request is within 2 minutes. I can't get this timeout higher.